# Haskell: Combinations (list of list)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of subjects and weekdays, on which the subject is taught.

```
subjectDays = [("maths", ["mon", "tue"]),
               ("science", ["mon", "wed"])]
```

Now I would like to generate a list of combinations.
The result should look like as follows.

```
combinations = [[("maths", "mon"), ("science", "mon")],
                [("maths", "mon"), ("science", "wed")]
                -- etc.
               ]
```

Could anyone please help me to write a function in *Haskell* to produce the above result?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are an infinite number of strings that, presumably, are not valid days for a class to meet. Use a more specific type instead, something like: `data ClassDay = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri`; then `subjectDays :: [(String, [ClassDay])]; subjectDays = [("maths", [Mon, Tue]), ("science", [Mon, Wed])]`.

Comment: @chepner yes, you're right. I updated my program with data types. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment below, I now realize that you want another output than the one I initially understood.

Essentially, you want each sublist to contain each subject (exactly once), paired with one of its days. If we still take `combinations` as defined below (the "wrong" output) we realize that we want to take the "cartesian product" of all the lists inside `combinations`. This cartesian product can be obtained using `Control.Monad.sequence`.

```
wantedCombinations = sequence combinations
```

---

Here's a hint.

First, write a function to expand a single pair of yours into a list.

```
combs :: (a,[b]) -> [(a,b)]
combs (subject, days) = ...
```

This could be solved using a list comprehension, for instance. Or `map`.

Then, we can apply `combs` to each pair in the list

```
combinations = map combs subjectDays
```

Comment: ```comb (subject, days) = [ (subject, d) | d <- days]```
but it produces a different result than I expected 

```[[("maths","mon"),("maths","tue")],[("science","mon"),("science","wed")]]```

Answer (score 0):

write an expand function to work on a single pair

```
expand :: (a,[b]) -> [(a,b)]
expand (x,[]) = []
expand (x,(y:ys)) = (x,y): expand (x,ys)
```

map to your structure and take the transpose (Data.List)

```
transpose $ map expand subjectDays
```